# Reboot Node using VSTS task or ARM template?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, azure-data-factory, azure-batch

I have a data factory v2 with a batch account, pool and a single node. It seems the node has gotten stuck in "waiting for start task state' and thus all my schedules stopped working.

I don't have the ability to reboot the node through the Azure Portal UI. Is there a way I can do it through a VSTS task or arm template?

Comment: you cannot do it from the arm template thats 101%

Answer (score 1):

You can restart a node only if it is in an idle or running state.

Get the information about the specified compute node.

```
GET {batchUrl}/pools/{poolId}/nodes/{nodeId}?api-version=2018-12-01.8.0
```

You can try with the below REST URI to reboot/restart a node and see if it resolves the issue.

```
POST {batchUrl}/pools/{poolId}/nodes/{nodeId}/reboot?api-version=2018-12-01.8.0
```

For more details, refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/batchservice/computenode/reboot